# Does 100% use of some core impacts performance of a process ( C++, multithreaded ) which is running on different core in Linux?

Tags: multithreading, boost, multicore

In a 32 core system, a process(A) consumes 4 core fully (400% cpu usage in top). Rest of the cores are avialble. Does it impact the performance of another process(B)? Will process(B) run better if process(A) is not running , then why ?

Process(B) is using boost and multiple threds ( say 24).

I was expecting performance of Process-B is not impacted by Process-A as there are 32 cores.

Answer (score 6):

In general, yes, running a process can slow down others even though not all cores are active. In practice, the impact is strongly dependent of the code being executed.

This can happen because **some hardware resources are shared**. The most common ones are storage devices, the network, the RAM, the LLC cache (typically a L3). For example, few cores are generally enough to saturate the RAM bandwidth so using more than 8 cores is generally not significantly faster if the two processes are memory bound. HDD storage devices tends to not be faster in parallel so when 2 processes try to massively use it at the same time they are often significantly slower. In practice, they can be more than 2 times slower because HDD have a high fetch time and a process doing many random accesses can drastically slow down a process reading/writing large contiguous files.

On NUMA systems, things can be a bit complex since 2 processes operating on the same NUMA node can be slower than 2 processes running on different NUMA node due to a saturation of the RAM of the target node and the NUMA allocation policy. In some rare case, 2 processes running on different NUMA nodes can be slower than running on the same NUMA node. This is true if the processes communicate each other (due to the higher latency between core belonging to different NUMA nodes) or if the processes communicate with hardware resources bound to specific NUMA nodes that is not the ones where the processes are running (eg. a GPU with a high-performance interconnect, a high-performance Infiniband device, etc.)

Note that **some software resources can also be shared**. The operating system can lock them so to ease the maintenance of some parts of its code or just because the resource cannot fundamentally be used in parallel in a way that can scale. Historically, some OS used a [giant lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_lock) preventing nearly all system call to scale. Such lock has been progressively replaced with finer-grained locks or no lock at all (eg. atomics) due to the democratisation of the multi-core processors. Note that even atomic data structures do not scale very well on most processors so system calls operating on the same data structure tends to impact other running processes on many-core systems. Still, the biggest issue is generally the saturation of shared hardware resources.

Comment: Yup, L3 cache footprint and DRAM bandwidth are the major shared resources for number crunching tasks (that don't make a lot of system calls or I/O).

Comment: All of the above is correct. There are even pathological hardware factors that can cause a slow-down. For example, 4 cores running full speed might overheat the chip, and then the chip might start throttling itself in order to avoid burning.